# How to add/join several g functions to obtain intra and interspecific spatial patterns in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

Considering a plant community, whose one of the objectives is to investigate intra and interspecific spatial patterns, I would like to know whether by evaluating the patterns of each pair equal (intra) and different (inter), and then adding them together (intra 1 + intra 2 .. + intra n, for example) I could get the intraspecific spatial behavior of the community.

Completely following this reasoning, I hope that:
`g intraespecif = ∑ gii (for all species);`
`g interespecif = ∑ gij (for all species);`
`gall = g univariate for the whole set of points = g intraespecific + g intrerispecific.`

Is this reasoning correct, if we consider using the function g for such a task?

I tried to apply this logic to the lansing data, but I wasn't successful, because when trying to add the g functions, I didn't get a general function.

```
data("lansing")
#all species
gall<-pcf(lansing, correction = c("Ripley"))
#behavior intraespecific
gb<-pcfcross(lansing, i="blackoak", j= "blackoak", correction = c("Ripley"))
gh<-pcfcross(lansing, i="hickory", j= "hickory", correction = c("Ripley"))
gm<-pcfcross(lansing, i="maple", j= "maple", correction = c("Ripley"))
gmi<-pcfcross(lansing, i="misc", j= "misc", correction = c("Ripley"))
gr<-pcfcross(lansing, i="redoak", j= "redoak", correction = c("Ripley"))
gw<-pcfcross(lansing, i="whiteoak", j= "whiteoak", correction = c("Ripley"))
gintra<- gb+gh+gm+gmi+gr+gw
```

Examining the class of objects, I saw that when adding the data of the functions that were "fv" objects, an object "data.frame" was created. When trying to convert the sum dataframe to an "fv" object, I got an error:

```
#trying to convert dataframe to "fv"
gintra(fv)<- as.fv(gintra)
Error in gintra(fv) <- as.fv(gintra) : could not find function "gintra<-"
```

Furthermore, when examining the dataframe resulting from the sum, I saw that the theoretical values went from 1 to 6, which may represent a certain inconsistency of my logic applied to the g function, I am confused about how I will achieve this goal.

Edit (more details): my reasoning was inspired by spatial aggregation functions from replicated patterns (WIEGAND; MOLONEY, 2014, p. 248 and 252; ILLAIN et al., 2008, p. 262). However, looking more carefully, I missed an important detail. In this context, for the pair correlation function, there is a denominator called "isotropised set covariance" which I have no idea how to estimate.

[image: Illian et al. (2008), p.262]

Regarding converting the dataframe resulting from the sums of g, I was able to transform it into fv with the command `as.fv.data.frame`, but when plotting it, the behavior of the g function does not appear.

[image]

Sources: ILLIAN, J. et al. Statistical analysis and modelling of spatial point patterns. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd: 2008. 534p.
WIEGAND, T.; MOLONEY, K. A. Handbook of spatial point pattern analysis in Ecology. Chapman & Hall (CRC): 2014. 512p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot of questions in one post.

Firstly you ask about the correct equations for aggregating multitype pair correlation functions.

> I would like to know whether by evaluating the patterns of each pair equal (intra) and different (inter), and then adding them together (intra 1 + intra 2 .. + intra n, for example) I could get the intraspecific spatial behavior of the community.
> Completely following this reasoning, I hope that: `g intraespecif = ∑ gii` (for all species); `g interespecif = ∑ gij` (for all species); `gall = g univariate` for the whole set of points `= g intraespecific + g intrerispecific`.

No, this is not quite true. The correct relationship is

```
lambda^2 g = sum[i] sum[j] lambda.i lambda.j g.ij
```

where g is the univariate pair correlation function of all points regardless of type (species); g.ij is the bivariate pair correlation function from points of type i to points of type j; lambda is the intensity of all points regardless of type; and lambda.i is the intensity of points of type i. Equivalently

```
g = sum[i] sum[j] p.i p.j g.ij
```

where `p.i = lambda.i/lambda` is the probability that a typical point belongs to type i. The "intraspecies" terms on the right hand side are the terms where `i=j`, that is, `p.i^2 g.ii` where `g.ii` is the univariate pair correlation function of the points of type `i`. See page 596 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org).

**Caveat:** The equations above assume that the point process is **stationary** (statistically homogeneous) which would need to be checked. If the density of points varies spatially, then you would need to use the inhomogeneous pair correlation functions. You could still pool the inhomogeneous pair correlation functions using the second equation above, but only if you believe that the probabilities `p.i` are constant (not spatially varying).

Next, you ask how to compute this in the `spatstat` packages. In `spatstat` the result of `pcf` is a function table (object of class `fv`). To do arithmetic with `fv` objects, we offer the function `eval.fv`. For example

```
  g1 <- pcf(cells)
  g2 <- pcf(redwood)
  g <- eval.fv(3 * g1 + 2 * g2)
```

See page 225 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) for further information about `eval.fv`. (If you install the latest development version of `spatstat.explore` you can avoid the `eval.fv` and just type the arithmetic expression `3*g1 + 2*g2` etc)

For some of the summary functions in `spatstat`, the pooling operation can be done automatically (for example you can do the corresponding operation with the *K* functions by computing each *K* function with `Kcross(, ratio=TRUE)` and then apply the function `pool` to the *K* functions). See pages 680-682 of the spatstat book. However this is not yet implemented for the pair correlation function.

Comment: Thank you very much, Professor. Based on the relationship you demonstrated, I was able to compute gii and gij for all pairs in the lansing data. Too bad there is no `pool` function for the g function, I will have to calculate in the "manual" for approximately 18 species of my data, it will be fun. Many thanks, again, `spatstat` is wonderful.

Comment: I have implemented the option `ratio=TRUE` for `pcfcross` in the development version of `spatstat.explore` (3.1-0.018 and later) available at the GitHub repository `spatstat/spatstat.explore`. Example: `A <- alltypes(amacrine, pcfcross, ratio=TRUE); g <- pool(A$fns)`